# javascript timer not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I have spent last few hours trying to understand why my javascript timer is not working for http://www.filmas-online.lv/o-winnie-the-pooh-2011-dvdrip this movie and why it is working for this one http://www.filmas-online.lv/o-vinnijs-puks-winnie-the-pooh-2011-dvdrip.

They seem identic in the code or am I missing something?

P.S. The timer is on the black backgrounds top right corner, at first it shows Ielāde (it means loadin) and then a countdown starts from 5 to zero.

Comment: Where is your code? Post relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check your browser for error logs? Opera reveals the error:

```
Syntax error at line 203 while loading: in string literal: invalid line terminator.
ip&rek=1'>Turpināt uz 
--------------------^
```

Change the following lines:

```
$('.aizvert_rek').html("<div class=white><a href='o-winnie-the-pooh-2011-dvdrip&rek=1'>Turpināt uz 
Winnie the Pooh 
 (2011) DVDRip</a></div>");
```

To:

```
$('.aizvert_rek').html("<div class=white><a href='o-winnie-the-pooh-2011-dvdrip&rek=1'>Turpināt uz Winnie the Pooh (2011) DVDRip</a></div>");
```

Or:

```
$('.aizvert_rek').html("<div class=white><a href='o-winnie-the-pooh-2011-dvdrip&rek=1'>Turpināt uz /
Winnie the Pooh /
 (2011) DVDRip</a></div>");
```

That should solve your problem.